# Google maps isn't loading properly (Google Maps API v2.0 for Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I'm new to android development, and are currently having an issue. I'm trying to get google maps to work inside an app I'm working on, but I'm having an issue; the map won't load.

This is what it looks like when I'm running the application;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuOLU.png

So the basic google maps is there, but it seems I'm not being fed data from their servers, which is very unfortunate. I'm certain the emulator has internet acces. It should also be comptable with google maps (genymotion). And I've also tried this on my actual android device (Samsung Galaxy S2). Same thing happens there.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="no.nith.myweathermap"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <permission android:name="no.nith.myweathermap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="no.nith.weatherwap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="myAPIkey(edited out for stackoverflow)" />
        <activity android:name=".StartActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

-

```
package no.nith.myweathermap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class StartActivity extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

layout/Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="blabla"
/>
```

Are anyone of you able to spot why the map isn't loading? I'm stuck here, and would greatly appreciate all feedback and help!

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Mapfragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html) since the [Mapactivity](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity) class is deprecated. Here is a sample app I have worked a few weeks ago to display a Map.

```
public class Map extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

layout activity_map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.napster.ft.bda"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name="com.napster.ft.bda.Map" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="<YOUR API KEY HERE>" />
</application>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you import google play services into your project and also turn on the  Google Maps Android API v2 from [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

I think you should probably watch out this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)
Might be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Use `FragmentActivity` instead of `MapActivity`.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your xml file use following code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Dont forgot to import library project of google play services into your project here is location of your google play services project.
**\your-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject**

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Whenever I change my StartActivity-class to use FragmentActivity instead of MapActivity, and use the code you provided  - the app just crash before it's even booting. Any idea why?

Comment: Same problem, unfortunately. Are there any tools available to see what's causing the crash?

Comment: You have to import google play services library project in your project.

Comment: Google-play-services is imported. That's not the issue. Whenever I try to boot the app, I get a popup saying the app unexpectedly crashed.

From what I can see in the log this is the error: http://pastebin.com/qvrUaMga

Answer (score 0):

I think after looking at your code, this is not version 2 of map library of android..

Cause in new library you have to use **MapFragment** or **SupportMapFragment** for maps from google-play service library, extending you activity from **MapActivity** is old school (i mean version 1).

I think you need to have a look at simple first example to get http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html.

I hope this will get you going with the new android maps.